# Slow MySQL query (mySQLdump)

Tags: mysql

I have checked all the slow queries on my MySQL 5.7 server (running on AWS RDS) and mangaged to reduce all of them below 1 sec.
But there is still a bottleneck - MySQLdump.
There is one query that lasts over a MINUTE!
In the slow_log table it shows:

```
SELECT
/*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */
*
FROM
`mail`
```

this table is not very large (95601 rows) there are much larger tables that are dumped faster.
Any idea what can be the reason for that?

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mail` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `instance_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `subject` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `body` longtext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci,
 `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tracking` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `read_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `mail_FI_1` (`instance_id`),
 KEY `address` (`address`(255)),
 KEY `createdAt` (`created_at`),
 KEY `mail_tracking` (`tracking`),
 KEY `mail_address_type` (`address`,`type`),
 KEY `mail_type_instance_created` (`type`,`instance_id`,`created_at`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95777 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci
```

```
+------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation      | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| mail | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 79634 |           1720 |   137003008 |               0 |     26853376 |         0 |          95951 | 2020-06-05 13:37:12 | 2020-06-17 22:14:59 | NULL       | utf8_polish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please post TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mail'; for a better idea of the space occupied by the table's 95,777 rows.    What would be a reasonable length of time to complete the dump?

Comment: Wilson, to be honest I do not know. What bothers me is: 1) a minute is too much; 2) there are much larger tables that take 1-2 secondes to be dumped

Comment: Avg_row_length - 1720; Data_length - 137003008; Index_length - 26853376;

Comment: We are looking forward to seeing the TEXT results of SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mail'; for a better idea of the space occupied by the table's 95,777 rows.  Also add similar status for 2 or 3 of the 'much larger' tables that are dumping in 1 - 2 secondes.  We should be able to offer some observed reasons for the difference in the time required to complete the dumps.

Comment: We need all the output, please.

Comment: I have added the result to the question. The other tables have more rows but their size is smaller ... My mistake.

Comment: As usual, size does matter.  Bigger takes longer to complete the dump.  The very best to you.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.